# Stack two FontAwesome icons

Tags: css, font-awesome

I need to group 2 icons like [image: this]. I've tried to use fa-stack class but it overlaps the images and I don't know how to put one above another.

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
<i class="fa fa-envelope fa-stack-1x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h fa-stack-2x"></i>
</span>
```

Comment: The same way you would put any HTML element over the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using same structure, you can move the second icon little up using css negative margin.

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
  <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-stack-1x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h fa-stack-2x"></i>
</span>

span i:not(:first-child){
  margin-top:-15px;
}
```

Here is an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/8L1qc6ec/)